# Android populate a String array in a do while statement

Tags: android

I want to populate a String array in a do while statement like below, I can populate a TextView with the code but I need to be able to click on through, if you know what I mean.

It's not all here but I hope you get my drift.

```
String[] theLocations = { };

do {        
    //...Here I would like to fill theLocations with the same values as output below
    output.append("\n\n" + BeachName + " - " + distence + "Kms");           
} while (theCursor.moveToNext());
```

I guess I will need the _id field also!

Cheers,

Mike.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with array is that it has a fixed size, and while loop usually don't run a fixed number of times.

There are two better options:

1. Use `StringBuilder`:

   ```
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   do {        
       sb.append("\n\n" + BeachName + " - " + distence + "Kms");           
   } while (theCursor.moveToNext());
   ```
2. Use `ArrayList<String>`:

   ```
   List<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>();
   do {        
       ar.add("\n\n" + BeachName + " - " + distence + "Kms");           
   } while (theCursor.moveToNext());
   ```

Comment: You can do a `String[]theLocation = ar.toArray(new String[ar.size()])` at the end to get an array.

Comment: Thanks Binyamin and @Njzk2 but as I was using ArrayAdapter, not in the above code to populate my list List<String> ar = new ArrayList<String>(); worked perfectly and first time. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
cursor.getCount()
```

to initialize your String[]:

```
String[] theLocations = new String[cursor.getCount()]
int index = 0;
while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
    theLocations[index++] = cursor.getString(column);
}
```